# Flex Custom Component with More Inside

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, components, custom-component

I am creating a custom component in Flex with extends the `BorderContainer` class, and I would like to be able to place additional content within the tagset when I use it in my main application, like this:

```
<components:CustomComponent title="Hello">
    <s:Label text="If you have one enter it below:"/>
    <mx:Spacer height="15" />

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:TextInput width="250"/>
        <s:Button label="Submit"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</components:CustomComponent>
```

This works just fine, except that my component definition had some additional things inside of it, such as a `<s:Label/>` and styling, which is replaced by the content within the tagset above when I go to use it.

If I do not put anything within the tagset, the content that was originally in the component is not replaced.

Is there a way that I can simply append additional content inside of the component when I go to use it, instead of it being replaced each time?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "simply", you have to work around it.
Here's a blog post with the gory details, including a sample app with source code: http://www.munkiihouse.com/?p=37 (step 3)

In summary, you script the class to intercept the child components being set to the default "dummy" property, and add them to your "main" property/container later.

The main property is the one you have your existing elements in in your custom component definition. The dummy property is the default property that a component instance will add elements to.

Good luck.

Comment: @spryno724 Though technically this solution may work, it completely disregards the Spark architecture. A much cleaner approach would be to simply use SkinnableContainer and create a custom Skin for it (one that contains the additional Label and styling). Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930740/what-is-the-hostcomponent/9931286#9931286) that describes a situation that is pretty similar to yours (except you don't even have to subclass SkinnableContainer, because you have no properties to expose or special behaviour to add).